# When I try to run a node program,it throwed a error,the error code is 4058

Tags: mkdir

When I try to run a node program.

```
fs.mkdir("E:\\test\\1",function(err){   
    console.log(err);
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('创建文件夹成功')
 })
```

However, it throws an error as below

```
error information is "[Error:ENOENT,mkdir 'E:\test\1 ]   
errno:-4058,code:'ENOENT',path:'E:\\test\\1'".
```

Comment: Use this module https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#mkdirsdir-callback to replace `fs.mkdir`